# S3 Presigned URLs and Data Charges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-billing

If you give someone a presigned URL, what's to stop them from downloading the object in a loop and running up your data bill? There's a "requester pays" feature, but that only works if they have their own account.

Comment: Nothing stops them. Set short timeout to limit this possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the S3 Presigned URL feature, you have control over the time when the URL is valid.

```
PutObjectPresignRequest presignRequest = PutObjectPresignRequest.builder()
                    **.signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(10))**
                    .putObjectRequest(objectRequest)
                    .build();
```

So you do not leave it open for very long if you have such concerns.

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the only thing you can really do. Maybe the better option is for the backend to retrieve the content from S3 and send it to the user. That way, your application can perform rate-limiting, etc.